# Triggering the update message in Erlang hot code reload feature

Tags: erlang, monitor, hot-code-replace

I am trying the hot code feature of erlang following the guide from [LYAE](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application#hot-code-loving) but i do not understand how to make the `update` message to get triggered.

I have a module which runs a method that is upgradeable:

**Module**

```
-module(upgrade).
-export([main/1,upgrade/1,init/1,init_link/1]).
-record(state,{ version=0,comments=""}).


init(State)->
    spawn(?MODULE,main,[State]).
main(State)->
    receive 
        update->
            NewState=?MODULE:upgrade(State),
            if NewState#state.version>3 -> exit("Max Version Reached") end,

            ?MODULE:main(NewState);
        SomeMessage->
            main(State)
    end.



upgrade(State=#state{version=Version,comments=Comments})->
    Comm=case Version rem 2 of
            0 -> "Even version";
            _ -> "Uneven version"
         end,
    #state{version=Version+1,comments=Comm}.
```

**Shell**

```
>c(upgrade).
>rr(upgrade,state).
>U=upgrade:init(#state{version=0,comments="initial"}).
>Monitor=monitor(process,U).
> ......to something to trigger the update message
> flush().  % see the exit message reason
```

I do not understand how can i perform a hot code reload in order to trigger the `update` message.
I want when i use `flush` to get the exit reason from my `main` method.

Comment: You are going to have to show the `......to something to trigger the update message` part of your code. But based on how you have things setup, it looks like if you send that process an `update` message, it will update itself. So in your specific example, if you `U ! update`, it will call the upgrade function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process expects to get the atom `update` as a message. Since you have the pid of the process in the variable `U`, you can send the message like this:

```
U ! update.
```

Note that the strings `Even version` and `Uneven version` are only kept in the state, never printed, so you won't see those.  The only thing you'll see is the exit message, after sending `update` four times and calling `flush()`.

Comment: I thought the `update` message is generated automatically whenever i am recompiling the target module.So in order to get the update i have to send the message after each `c(module)`

Comment: Yes, you need to send the message explicitly.